# Disposing a TabPage control and its controls

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, user-controls, tabcontrol

My application uses `TabControl` to show data, each time the user asks for data the application will create a new `TabPage` which contains many controls (`PictureBox` controls, `Label` controls, .etc). The user at some point will close the `TabPage` controls he is done working with. Now the problem here is the closed `TabPage` controls, they will pile up in the memory causing the program to use a huge part of the memory. Removing the `TabPage` controls from the `TabControl` does not dispose it nor dispose the items within, it just hides it but the control still hangs in the memory.

The code I am using to remove the `TabPage` is something like:

```
tabControl.TabPages.Remove(myTabPage);
myTabPage.Dispose();
```

**Q: How do I totally get rid of the `TabPage` controls?**

Comment: CL4PTR4P - This is not a question of what has he tried It's obvious that's he's tried something.. the question I would ask is to see the source code that he's written and look at how he is currently Disposing the current Tab(s)

Comment: @DJKRAZE - From what I read, I don't think he is disposing of them _at all_.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Yes, he's tried "something", but what was it?  But you have a point, code here would be helpful as well.

Comment: Brian exactly the point that is why I suggested showing the code.. too many OP's on here want quick answers I can tell based on `HaLaBi` question that he has shown / put in some individual effort the question he's asking displays that.. now if we could see some code then we will be able to help in regards to a viable solution

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have included some code.. this is how I generally dispose them.

Comment: You've called Dispose (so you're all set there), as long as you don't have any references to myTabPage remaining, then eventually the garbage collector will do its work and free up the memory.

Comment: That code cannot cause a control leak.  I seriously doubt it is real code with an identifier like "myTabPage".  It otherwise fits the pattern of the *kind* of code that can cause permanent control leaks, Clear() and Remove() are dangerous.

Comment: HaLaBi take a look at this link this will serve of a good starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047012/i-want-my-memory-back-how-can-i-truly-dispose-a-control

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate every time through the tabpage controls associated with it and dispose them in a loop.

```
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls[i].Dispose();
```

Comment: I do not think this will solve the issue, disposing a parent control should dispose its children controls.

Answer (score 0):

Calling myTabPage.Dispose() should dispose the resource of the TabPage and its children. However, the memory used by these objects might not be necessarily released right away by GC, even if these objects are not referenced by the others.

In a computer with very large memory, GC tends to be lazy. As long as the memory will be released later, say, minutes later, you don't need to worry.

Comment: @HaLaBi, It sure would be nice if you told us *how* you are sure.  Why don't you *force* a garbage collection, and see if those objects are still in memory.